# What's the proper storage location for a database for a cross platform command line program?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I wrote a simple note taking program that's nothing more than a dictionary mapping a key to a value. IE

```
$ hlp -key age -value 25
$ hlp age
  25
```

and it just stores information in a json file hardcoded to `~/.hlp.json`. But I was wondering if there's likely some standard location I should be putting this file. Is there a standard location for databases like this?

Comment: Quite a subjective question! I would grant myself a whole directory (e.g. `~/.hlp`) like `ssh` does with `~/.ssh` so I have more flexibility with potentially multiple different databases and an options/config file. If data is shared between users, I would go for `/usr/local/something`.

Comment: Not `/usr/local`. System-wide writeable data should go somewhere under `/var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful resource here is the [hier(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/hier) man page. (http://linux.die.net/man)

Data that is only going to be used by you belongs in `$HOME`, traditionally hosted under `/home`.

For something that is used to support the system itself, you'd be using `/var`.  For applications that are just hosted on the system, you'd use `/var/opt`.

If the application is something big that could be replicated or moved to another system, you'd create a separate filesystem with a mount point *outside* any of those listed in `hier(7)`.  This could be a filesystem mounted from a SAN or NAS, which whould help mobility of the application.

Once you actually need to access the data from different machines, you'd have to move it to a network accessable key/value store or sql database.